# is Breeze.js contradicting with SOA?

Tags: architecture, breeze, soa

I have some architecture as mentioned in the image.

Services layer is an SOA implementation with CRUD calls to DB via UOW pattern + repository pattern. further i am working on SPA that calls these web APIs.

When i studied Breeze.js it shook my SOA concepts. All Breeze requires is the calls to GetAll and GetById like methods and rest can be controlled at client side.

My question is where should i put all my business logic ?  One answer could be in in methods like BeforeSaveChanges but isn't it contradicting with SOA concepts?

[image: Architecture]

Comment: Check questions and answers in this post: http://www.johnpapa.net/spajs04/ and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026988/where-doese-breeze-fits-into-ntier-architecture

Comment: non of this answers my SOA concern.